# Is there a simple way to get the values of a list in a comma separated string all in once

Tags: apex, list, dynamic-soql, string, custom-metadata

I have a custom metadata type in which I want to add the API names of some custom fields to use the values in a Dynamic Soql. I used a list to get the values of the custom metadata fields. Is there a simple way to put the values of the list in a comma separated string to use this in a dynamic Soql. With for example a .get or describe?

Field

```
A__c = Test1__c
B__c = Test2__c
C__c = Test3__c
```

For example:

```
List<CustomMetadata__mdt> cFieldsValues = [SELECT A__c, B__c, C__c FROM CustomMetadata__mdt];

String soqlstring = '';
for (Integer x = 0; x < cFieldsValues.size(); x++){
    soqlstring += cFieldsValues[x].get;
}
Result
soqlstring='Test1__c,Test2__c,Test3__c';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When You say

> I used a list to get the values of the custom metadata fields.

First of all, You should consider that `[SELECT A__c, B__c, C__c FROM CustomMetadata__mdt]` SOQL returns you a list of CMT records, not fields. So if You want to get a concrete record of CMT you should specify filter conditions `[SELECT A__c, B__c, C__c FROM CustomMetadata__mdt WHERE DeveloperName = 'CMTRecordName']`

Assume You have one single record of `CustomMetadata__mdt` and the type of the queried CMT fields is `String` and you want to dynamically collect the values of the fields. Then you can use [`getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) method which returns a map of populated field names and their corresponding values:

```java
CustomMetadata__mdt record = [
    SELECT 
        A__c, 
        B__c, 
        C__c /*, D__c, ..., N__c */ 
    FROM custommetadata 
    WHERE DeveloperName = 'CMTRecordName'
];
Map<String, Object> populatedFieldsAsMap = record.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap(); 
populatedFieldsAsMap.keySet().remove('Id'); /* Id field is queried by default */
String soqlstring = String.join(populatedFieldsAsMap.values(), ',');
/* soqlstring = 'Test1__c,Test2__c,Test3__c'  */
```

Generally, You can use [`String.join()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_methods_system_string) method to join the elements of the specified iterable object, such as a `List`, into a single string separated by the specified separator.

For instance:

```java
List<String> simpleList = new List<String>{'Test1__c', 'Test2__c', 'Test3__c'};
String soqlstring = String.join(simpleList, ',');
/* soqlstring = 'Test1__c,Test2__c,Test3__c'  */
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it was very concise.